# Is X day 0-14 days away?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of holidays. How can I detect if there's an upcoming holiday in 0-14 days? Is there a better way to store the holiday?

```
var holidays = ["Tue Jul 04 2017", "Mon Sep 04 2017", "Mon Oct 09 2017", "Fri Nov 10 2017", "Thu Nov 23 2017", "Mon Dec 25 2017", "Mon Jan 01 2018", "Mon Jan 15 2018"];

if(holiday ???) console.log("Today is a holiday, or there is one soon.");
```

Comment: you should better think of a suitable description, 

"plz provide an algorithm for calculating a difference between two dates"

I propose to

Comment: It's using the holiday API ^^

Comment: SO you loop over, convert it to a date object and check

Answer (score -1):

The basic code would look something like this.

```
var holidays = ["Tue Jul 04 2017", "Mon Sep 04 2017", "Mon Oct 09 2017", "Fri Nov 10 2017", "Thu Nov 23 2017", "Mon Dec 25 2017", "Mon Jan 01 2018", "Mon Jan 15 2018"];
var today = new Date();

for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
    date = new Date(holidays[i]);
    if(compareDate(today, date) {
        console.log("..");
    }
}
```

The `compareDate` function would use the `.fullYear()`, `.getMonth()` and `.getDate()` methods to compare the year, month and day.

Hope this helps!

P.S.: You can also use momentjs to compare dates and easily make calculations using dates.